# How to raise dunning level in a document?

Tags: abap, sap-data-dictionary

I want to raise the dunning level from '3' to '4' in a document for 1 when I change the dunning from 'L' to 'N' for example. I need a simple function but I cant find it. Anybody have an idea?

I have data for debitor, document number, booking date etc..

Comment: Simple function for automatic trigger? Are you serious? Somebody just believes in fairy-tails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no formal function modules for your requirement. You can use standard FI [Substitution](https://blogs.sap.com/2014/06/06/create-fi-substitutions-using-ggb1-substitution-maintenance/) function which fits to your use case. Transaction code is GBB1.